# Autohotkey angle bracket

Tags: autohotkey

Hi I start use autohotkey, I have a simple script to run `cmd` and execute some command, like this:

> echo ^Q>COM5

Autohotkey script:

```
run cmd.exe
WinWait, ahk_exe cmd.exe ;
Send ECHO ^{Q}>COM{Numpad5}{enter}
```

But right angle bracket gets displayed as dot.

I also tried instead of >,  (asc 0062) or !{.}

Where do I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Send {Raw}` to send literal strings.  You would need to put the `{Numpad5}{enter}` in a separate send statement that is not a send {raw}, but you can split the text you need to send into as many send statements as needed.

You can also launch the command directly using a run statement--that may or may not be of interest to you, but saves having to send keyboard input to the command window.

Answer (score 0):

You send upper case Q which also implies the Shift key being sent. 
Sending to the console can be a bit tricky, the developer of AutoHotkey has made a separate function which may help, ConsoleSend() by Lexikos here https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/25446-consolesend/

You can send the text using ConsoleSend() and then a regular Send for the numpad+enter keys